# java spring 4 @Transactional nested transaction issue

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class:

```
@Transactional
public class MyClass{
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void method1(){
         ....
         myDao.update(entity);
    }

    public void method2(){
         method1();             
         //I need to be sure that data was persisted to DB and find the entity by id    

         MyEntity ent=myDao.find(entityId);
         //entity is not updated here
    }

}
```

But in fact I can't read updated entity from DB in method2. How to achieve this?
I need in method2 to have updated value after method1() invocation, so transaction in method1 should be committed and the results are visible. How to do that?

Comment: Because of the @Transactional at the class level method2 and method1 will run in the same transaction. There won't be a commit after method1, but you should see the results of the save/update from method1 in method2. If you don't then the problem is elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do this from within another class, since `@Transactional` isn't obeyed when calling local methods (this is down to the way that Spring proxying works, local method calls bypass the transactional proxy by calling `this`).

The solution would probably looks something like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    public void performAction() {
       myClass.method1();
       myClass.find(entityId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated Your scenario like (embeded database): 
First I add anything to the database like:

```
 public void initialize() {
    Sample startEntity = new Sample();
    startEntity.setId(1);
    startEntity.setName("Start name");
    sampleRepository.saveSample(startEntity);
    sampleRepository.flush(); // <-- just to make sure scenario is recreated
    sampleRepository.clear(); // same as above
    LOGGER.info(sampleRepository.findSampleById(1));
    sampleRepository.clear(); // same as above above :D
}
```

After that, we got one entity Sample in database (all transactions are over and cache is cleared);

Console:

```
Hibernate: insert into sample (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select sample0_.id as id1_0_0_, sample0_.name as name2_0_0_ from sample sample0_ where sample0_.id=?
2016-04-20 15:58:21.762  INFO 5764 --- [           main] com.patrykwoj.service.BasicServiceTest   : Sample [id=1, name=Start name]
```

Now Your example:

```
@Transactional
@Component
public class SampleService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SampleService.class);

@Autowired
SampleRepository sampleRepository;

@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void method1() {
    Sample someSample = new Sample();
    someSample.setId(1);
    someSample.setName("TestSample before update but after create");
    sampleRepository.updateSample(someSample);
}

public void method2() {
    method1();
    // I need to be sure that data was persisted to DB and find the entity by id

    Sample someSampleAfterUpdate = sampleRepository.findSampleById(1); //I believe that at that point sample is found in L-1 cache not in db directry.
    // entity is not updated here
    LOGGER.info(someSampleAfterUpdate); //in this point, transaction is not over yet, so you wont notice change in database..
}
}
```

And then console from Your code execution:

```
Hibernate: select sample0_.id as id1_0_0_, sample0_.name as name2_0_0_ from sample sample0_ where sample0_.id=?
2016-04-20 16:02:17.903  INFO 5044 --- [           main] com.patrykwoj.service.SampleService      : Sample [id=1, name=TestSample before update but after create]
Hibernate: update sample set name=? where id=?
2016-04-20 16:02:17.903  INFO 5044 --- [           main] com.patrykwoj.StackOverfloApplication    : Method2 is over
```

Main class:

```
@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
  basicServiceTest.initialize();
  sampleService.method2();
  LOGGER.info("Method2 is over");
}
```

In my opinion everything looks good. It worked as expected. I made some comments at Your code, but console output should be clear anyway.